# TinyMCE Plugin Template add category Listbox

Tags: javascript, templates, plugins, listbox, tinymce

I'm developping for my entreprise an external template manager with ASP.net.

in this external template manager, users can execute all the CRUD actions, so they can create/ read /update /delete.

Many departements of my entreprise use thoses templates, so I've created a category fields in my template manager, so they can filter a bit.

I'would like to modify, the plugin.js of the [template plugin](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/template/) to add a dynamic listbox category.

So when a user want to add a template in the editor he can select his departements[category] and only the related template will be shown in the listbox [template].

I get all the template definition[title, content, description, category] from a MS SQL DB with an ASP repeater Control.

the result of the repeater generate the definition needed by the template plugin

```
templates:
[
{"title": "Some title 1", "description": "Some desc 1", "content": "My 
content", "category": "support"},
]
```

So i've tried just to test (because i'm not good with JS ad Oriented Object) :
`
               win = editor.windowManager.open({
               title: 'Insert template',
          layout: 'flex',
          direction: 'column',
          align: 'stretch',
          padding: 15,
          spacing: 10,

```
      items: [
        {
          type: 'form', flex: 0, padding: 0, items: [
            {
              type: 'container', label: 'Templates', items: {
                type: 'listbox', label: 'Templates', name: 'template', 
        values: values, onselect: onSelectTemplate

              }
               //Added BY ME
              type: 'container', label: 'Category', items: {
                type: 'listbox', label: 'Category', name:'category', values: 
              valuesCategory, onselect: onSelectCategory
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        { type: 'label', name: 'description', label: 'Description', text: 
        '\u00a0' },
        { type: 'iframe', flex: 1, border: 1 }
      ],

      onsubmit: function () {
        insertTemplate(false, templateHtml);
      },

      minWidth: Math.min(DOMUtils.DOM.getViewPort().w, 
      editor.getParam('template_popup_width', 600)),
      minHeight: Math.min(DOMUtils.DOM.getViewPort().h, 
      editor.getParam('template_popup_height', 500))
    });

    win.find('listbox')[0].fire('select');
       win.find('listbox')[0].fire('select');
  }`
```

and defined valuesCategory & onSelectCategory somewhere over that.

the list box isn't showed in the Dialog ?

I've searched on internet to find something similar with tinymce but i don't find anything like this, could someone help me to develop this functionnality ?

Thanks for your answers !

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of modifying the editor's source code why not calculate the valid plugins from the server side and only include the relevant templates in the editor configuration?

This eliminates the need for you to modify the source code of the editor and people will not have the ability to see templates for a different department.

Comment: If that solved your issue can you mark this as the answer so others will not spend time providing additional answers? Thanks.